# Akka cannot start ActorSystem

Tags: scala, akka

I've been following the [QuickStart guide for Akka Streams](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.4.12/scala/stream/stream-quickstart.html#stream-quickstart-scala) and I'm running into an error. My code is simple:

```
object Main extends App {
  implicit val system = ActorSystem("QuickStart")
  implicit val materializer = ActorMaterializer()

  val source: Source[Int, NotUsed] = Source(1 to 100)
  source.runForeach(i => println(i)) (materializer)
}
```

However this results in an error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/Product$class
>       at akka.util.Timeout.(Timeout.scala:13)
>       at akka.actor.ActorSystem$Settings.(ActorSystem.scala:179)
>       at akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl.(ActorSystem.scala:530)
>       at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:142)
>       at akka.actor.ActorSystem$.apply(ActorSystem.scala:109)
>       at streams_test.Main$.delayedEndpoint$streams_test$Main$1(Main.scala:14)
>       at streams_test.Main$delayedInit$body.apply(Main.scala:13)
>       at scala.runtime.AbstractFunction0.apply$mcV$sp(AbstractFunction0.scala:12)
>       at scala.App.$anonfun$main$1$adapted(App.scala:76)
>       at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:378)
>       at scala.App.main(App.scala:76)
>       at scala.App.main$(App.scala:74)
>       at streams_test.Main$.main(Main.scala:13)
>       at streams_test.Main.main(Main.scala)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
>       at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:147)
>   Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.Product$class
>       at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
>       at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
>       at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
>       ... 19 more

I've also tried running it through the sbt console with no luck. Does anyone know what's causing this issue? It is being throwed at the line:

```
implicit val system = ActorSystem("QuickStart")
```

As requested, my `build.sbt` file:

```
name := "Akka_test"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.12.0"

// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-actor_2.11
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-actor_2.11" % "2.3.9"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.typesafe.akka/akka-stream_2.11
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe.akka" % "akka-stream_2.11" % "2.4.12"
// https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.twitter4j/twitter4j-core
libraryDependencies += "org.twitter4j" % "twitter4j-core" % "4.0.2"
```

Comment: This could be the Scala version problem you might be using the 2.10 compiled library with 2.11 compiler or vice versa

Comment: Could you please paste ur `build.sbt` file as well ?

Comment: sometimes it happens when you run compiled class with `java` instead of `scala`. You can use `java` on a packaged jar, but `java` will not put scala libraries on the classpath by default.

Comment: @pamu I have added the `build.sbt` file

Comment: @pamu I just got it working, it was indeed a versioning problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This could be the Scala version problem you might be using the 2.10 compiled library with 2.11 compiler or vice versa.

You can avoid running into the problem if you explicitly have scala version in build.sbt and use `%%` after groupId in build.sbt

use this

```
scalaVersion := "scala_version"

libraryDependencies += "group_id" %% "artificat_id" % "version"
```

instead of

```
libraryDependencies += "group_id" % "artificat_id_scala_version" % "version"
```

Comment: What to do for Java gradle?